# 0 is converted to 128

Tags: c, linux, snmp, data-conversion

I am trying to do SNMP Set from host Linux to target system. But, instead of correct values, wrong values are getting set. After a bit of research, I made this table:

## Hex representation of decimal value in Linux snmp

```
0 - 0x80 - 1000 0000 - 0 is converted to 128
1 - 0x40 - 0100 0000 - 1 is converted to 64
2   0x20 - 0010 0000 - 2 is converted to 32
3   0x10 - 0001 0000 - 3 is converted to 16
4   0x08 - 0000 1000 - 4 is converted to 8
5   0x04 - 0000 0100 - 5 is converted to 4
6   0x02 - 0000 0010 - 6 is converted to 2
7   0x01 - 0000 0001 - is converted to 1
```

## Hex representation of decimal value in target system

```
0 - 0x00 - 0000 0000
1 - 0x01 - 0000 0001
2   0x02 - 0000 0010
3   0x03 - 0000 0011
4   0x04 - 0000 0100
5   0x05 - 0000 0101
6   0x06 - 0000 0110
7   0x07 - 0000 0111
```

*I have two questions:*

1. What could be the reason behind this issue?
2. Does anyone know how I can convert those Linux values to correct target values in a C program?

Comment: wild guess: reverse the values bitwise and get the position of the "1" bit, and substract 1 => you'll get your number.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have a clue what you're asking here. Can you create a [mcve] to illustrate where your code is producing incorrect results?

Comment: All your values do seem correct. 0x80 _is_ 128 decimal, etc. So what is "wrong"? What do you expect the values to be?

Comment: An XY-problem ...?

Comment: Can you elaborate the circumstances a bit? How do you set the values? With the snmpset cli tool? What is the oid and the data type of the object? How do you check which values were set?

Comment: Please explain who told you that 0x80 is zero? It is not 1 complement. I think you vjust do not understand how negative numbers are represented

Comment: @PeterJ_01 There are eight possible values, numbered 0-7. In order, they go from 0x80, the first one, to 0x01, the last one. Nothing here is about ones' complement or negative numbers, they're just bit patterns. We're semi-implicitly talking about them as though they were unsigned binary numbers, even when that's not the intended meaning.

Comment: What I meant in the question is that if I am giving input as 1, then I am expected hex output as 0x01, instead I am getting 0x40 i.e. value is getting converted to 64, or some binary conversion is happening due to which I am getting 64,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you receive a byte that encode 8 values (0 to 7) using a one-hot encoding. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot (notice: your bit order seems reversed though).

If you simply put a one-hot encoded bit pattern into a byte variable on your target system, you'll **not** get the original value as your target system uses another encoding (probably 2's complement). In other words - a given bit pattern has different meanings in one-hot encoding and 2's complement encoding.

So the task is to convert the one-hot encoded values to equivalent values on your target system.

You could go for a simple switch-statement - like:

```
int main(void)
{
  unsigned char linux_snmp_value = 0x20;
  unsigned char target_value = 255;
  switch(linux_snmp_value)
  {
    case 0x80:
        target_value = 0;
        break;
    case 0x40:
        target_value = 1;
        break;
    case 0x20:
        target_value = 2;
        break;

    // Add the remaining cases here

    default:
        // Illegal value
        // Add some error handling
        break;
  }
  printf("Target value %d\n", target_value);
  return 0;
}
```

If you prefer a loop, it could be something like:

```
int main(void)
{
  unsigned char linux_snmp_value = 0x01;
  unsigned char target_value = 0;
  unsigned char mask = 0x80;
  while (mask)
  {
    if (mask == linux_snmp_value) break;
    ++target_value;
    mask = mask >> 1;
  }
  if (mask == 0)
  {
    // Illegal value
    // Add some error handling
    printf("ERROR\n");
    return -1;
  }
  printf("Target value %d\n", target_value);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although it is decidedly the perfect solution, I am afraid it won't work in my case. Regardless, thanks for the answer all the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the portability is not the issue (for example you do not play to compile on the VAX or AVR8 machine) you can use machine instructions for it

`asm (“bsrl %1, %0” : “=r” (position) : “r” (number));`

you can also wrap it into nice inline function. 
Similar instructions are available on ARM, MIPS, PIC and many other.